# Limiting access to Azure repositories

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-repos

I have an Azure DevOps project with multiple Repositories in one Project. I only want specific users to access specific repositories. How do I restrict the access per repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Sajeetharan.

> I only want specific users to access specific repositories.

You could open project setting->Repositories->select repo->search users and set the user permission **Read** to deny. Then the use will not see the repo. To give different rights to the use on other repositories, click on the repository name and then the group and change the individual security areas.

We could also create a permission group and add users to this group, then follow the steps share below to configure the repo permission for this group member.

You could refer to this [doc](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-devops-setting-up-repository-permissions/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by  Navigating to organization settings and then go to Project - Repositories and then you can restrict the access by Group or User

[image]